# Usdt Omni questions

Tags: altcoin

1 what is the transaction fee to sending usdt Omni version?
2 can I use Omni api to check the usdt I received ?any php script useful?
3 can I also use the Omni api to send usdt automatically? Any example? In php 
4 which platform is easy to buy and sell usdt and no need to verify a lot for id etc
5 how to easily exchange between erc20 usdt and Omni usdt
Thanks